# Google Script Gmail: parsing a .txt value

Tags: parsing, gmail

Im using Google Scripts to parse an attachment from Gmail which is .txt (it is separated by "|") and then paste it in a spread sheet.

.txt Example:

> 08006473900634|9470182100|16|2020-01-09|2019-12-31
>   08006473901259|9930822100|8|2020-01-08|2019-12-31
>   08006473029496|9930812100|6|2020-01-08|2019-12-31
>   08006473029489|9470082100|6|2020-01-09|2019-12-31

Right now, I can only parse it if its a csv file, using `utilities.parseCsv` function

Can somebody tell me what would be the right method to do this?

Below the part of my script for CSV.

```
if (threads.length != 0) {
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
    var attachName = message.getAttachments()[0].getName();
    var subject = message.getSubject();
    //Is the attachment a CSV file
    if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv" || attachment.getContentType() === "application/octet-stream") {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kyiyc4wB6yZVeO_Wcs2yeUk_pb");
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DATA");
        var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), "|");   
        sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

Comment: You can use the same method `parseCsv(csv, delimiter)`, have you tried it with `.txt` file ? If you are getting any error then  you can simple replace `|` with `,` in `attachment.getDataAsString()`. Let me know if it helps and I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Thank you! at first it didn't work, but not it does! amazing

Answer (score 0):

It worked with `parseCsv(csv, delimiter)`
Thank you!